# Mtgox: Probability of Distribution, etc. - Report 28 sept 2016

Tags: mtgox

In the last report regarding the MtGox bankruptcy it is mentioned that:

> *However,  the  detailed  schedule  thereof  will  inevitably  be  affected  by  each  creditor’s  response  to  the 
>   acceptance  or  rejection  of  his  or  her  claim,  etc.*

Does this mean that each user have to respond even if the claim was accepted?

Comment: I think you're better off taking this up with the bankruptcy trustee. We don't have any special insight into their policies.

Comment: @NickODell: I imagine that this question might be of interest to a greater number of MtGox creditors, so it appears to be useful here.

Comment: I could read this in the latest report also on page 12 https://www.mtgox.com/img/pdf/20170308_report.pdf. I have submitted a support ticket at Kraken and will update here with the information I get.

Comment: Got this message today. Will get back when i get more info. "Hi,

Sorry that you haven't received a reply to this support ticket yet.

We have seen a huge wave of incoming support requests and it is currently taking us several days to respond.

We want to apologize for the slow service and to let you know that we are working around the clock to ensure everyone receives a response as soon as possible. Thanks for your patience.

The Kraken Team"

Comment: Still no response from Kraken .... :s

Comment: Got this response 12 april: For most claim inquiries at this time, Kraken cannot help you and you must contact the MtGox trustee directly at the help desk phone number below. There is no email, only a phone number.